# figuring out how to get all of the public ips of a machine

Tags: python

I am running my code on multiple VPSes (with more than one IP, which are set up as aliases to the network interfaces) and I am trying to figure out a way such that my code acquires the IP addresses from the network interfaces on the fly and bind to it. Any ideas on how to do it in python without adding a 3rd party library ?

**Edit** I know about `socket.gethostbyaddr(socket.gethostname())` and about the 3rd party package `netifaces`, but I am looking for something more elegant from the standard library ... and parsing the output of the `ifconfig` command is not something elegant :)

Comment: What do you need the exact IP for? If you're writing a server and want to listen on all available addresses, then do something like `mysocket.bind(('', 12345))` to match every address.

Comment: I am writing a client and I want to round-robin between the addresses and give them work :)

Comment: Is it your goal to ask the server for all its addresses, then make your client connect to all of them? Or are you trying instead to pick which source address your client will be connecting from?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand the difference ... I am going to get all the addresses in order for the client to connect from each one of those.

Comment: No offense, but I don't think you've thought this through. It is very possible (and common!) for an interface to have non-routable addresses bound to it so that if you specify one of those addresses as your source address then you'll never be able to connect to the server.

Comment: I am totally open to discussion about this ... the thing is that the system I am building will be deployed on a number of X VPSes each with  3 routable addresses. So I think I can make the assumption that besides interface lo, all the other ones are routable.

Answer (score 0):

The IP addresses are assigned to your VPSes, no possibility to change them on the fly.

You have to open a SSH tunnel to or install a proxy on your VPSes.

I think a SSH tunnel would be the best way how to do it, and then use it as SOCKS5 proxy from Python.

Comment: Sorry, maybe I didn't phrase it right (English is not my mother tongue) ... I am trying to get the IP addresses of all network interfaces on that server. Is this more clear? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is how to get all IP addresses of the server the script is running on:

(this is as much elegant as possible and it only needs the standard library)

```
import socket
import fcntl
import struct
import array

def all_interfaces():
    max_possible = 128  # arbitrary. raise if needed.
    bytes = max_possible * 32
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
    names = array.array('B', '\0' * bytes)
    outbytes = struct.unpack('iL', fcntl.ioctl(
        s.fileno(),
        0x8912,  # SIOCGIFCONF
        struct.pack('iL', bytes, names.buffer_info()[0])
    ))[0]
    namestr = names.tostring()
    return [namestr[i:i+32].split('\0', 1)[0] for i in range(0, outbytes, 32)]
```